# Full Sandbox is really required?

Tags: sandbox, userlicense, full-sandbox

We have been paying for full sandbox license. Our setup is not complex and we feel it is not required to spend so much on full sandbox. Can someone suggest me If we should really have a full sandbox or If I remove the full sandbox will I still have the Developer sandbox and Partial sandbox. We use salesforce enterprise sales cloud and partner community.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Full Sandbox: A Full sandbox is intended to be used as a testing environment. Only Full sandboxes support performance testing, load testing, and staging. Full sandboxes are a replica of your production org, including all data, such as object records and attachments, and metadata. The length of the refresh interval makes it difficult to use Full sandboxes for development."

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=create_test_instance.htm&type=5

To make a decision on whether to continue to pay for Full Copy or not, ask your self following questions

1. What was the last time performance/load testing was done? Would you need to do it again in future?
2. What other option do you have for staging environment? Do you need all of organization data for UAT? Can't you do smoke testing in partial copy sandbox?

Answers of above two will help you in deciding whether to continue with full copy or not.

Answer (score 2):

As you are having Enterprise edition, you get these for free 25 Developer and 1 Partial Copy sandboxes.

The **full-copy**(and 10 additional dev sandboxes) is the **addon** bundle for Enterprise. So if you unsubscribe for that, you will still have 25 Dev and 1 partial copy sandbox. But remember that, you will lose those additional 10 dev sandboxes which come with the full copy bundle.

You can find more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_environments.htm&type=5).
The pricing for [sandboxes](https://www.salesforce.com/in/editions-pricing/platform/environments/).

**If we should really have a full sandbox?**
The fullcopy sandbox is generally used for load testing or performance testing. As you don't have a very complex system, having fullcopy is not needed in my opinion.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation